# How to lock screen rotation in the code on Android 4.2 and lower?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have used `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED` and `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` to control screen rotation in *Android 4.4*,it is good.But when I set the `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED` in *Android 4.2* ,it is useless.
How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want mode `landscape`?

Comment: you can set android:screenOrientation="portrait" or android:screenOrientation="landscape" in manifest

Comment: See my answer, if it solved your problem just mark it as a correct answer ;)

Comment: I want to realize a function that there is a ToggleButton,when it was checked the screen will can not be rotated if I rotate my devices,and when it was unchecked the screen will can rotate ,I have realized this function ,but it can not display in Android 4.2 like 360 Browser in Pad.

Comment: @user4689328 you'll have to override it programatically. Get the current orientation, then if you toggle to fix the state, set that as it's orientation, else  don't do anything.

Comment: Could you state this method plainly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to override it programatically. Get the current orientation, then if you toggle to fix the state, set that orientation as your application's orientation.

**For Example**:

```
int rotation=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                //ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 2, ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT=1 
                if(rotation==1){
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }else{
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
```

This will lock it to the current orientation.

And in order to release it, simply use `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR` like this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

That's it.

Now, the final code will look something like this:

```
     if(allow_screen_change.equals("yes")){ 
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    }else if(allow_screen_change.equals("no")){ 
   int rotation=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                    //ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE = 2, ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT=1 
                    if(rotation==1){
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    }else{
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                }
    }
```

I just made this and tested on HTC One X, running Android 4.2 and it works just fine. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

also you can use `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

And in your code something like

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Also you can see this [guide](http://techblogon.com/android-screen-orientation-change-rotation-example/).

Comment: if(allow_screen_change.equals("yes")){
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
  }else if(allow_screen_change.equals("no")){
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
  }

Comment: This method is good in Android 4.4 System,but bad in Android 4.2 ,such as huawei S8-301w.